# Transform a list of pointers to base class

Tags: c++, polymorphism, transform

I have a design where I have a `std::list` of base pointers that I'd like to transform into a parallel list that adds behavior. The problem I'm having is that the object that I'm trying to use to do the transform doesnt know what the actual types are when it is invoked.

It's quite possible that I'm missing something subtle and that there is an easy fix. However, if this is a design flaw (I've seen this suggested in other posts) what is the appropriate way to approach this?

Suppose the following:

```
class Sprite { /* ... */ };
class Character : public Sprite {};
class Markup : public Sprite {};
```

These are constructed (based on some input) into a `std::list< Sprite * >`. What I'd like to do is eventually take the list and transform it into a parallel structure suitable for output operations. For instance, given:

```
class HTMLSprite { /* ... */ };
class HTMLCharacter : public HTMLSprite {};
class HTMLMarkup : public HTMLSprite {};
```

I'd ideally like to do something like

```
std::transform(sprites.begin (), sprites.end (), html.begin (), HTMLConvert);
```

with something like

```
struct HTMLConvert_ {
  HTMLSprite * operator () (const Character * c) { return new HTMLCharacter (); }
  HTMLSprite * operator () (const Markup * c) { return new HTMLMarkup (); }
} HTMLConvert;
```

Now, I get the error

```
call of `(HTMLConvert) (const Sprite* const&)' is ambiguous
HTMLSprite* HTMLConvert::operator()(const Character*) const <near match>
```

Which leads me to my question. What is the best solution to this problem - redesign or otherwise?

Thanks.

Comment: Classic problem for the visitor pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to JoshD's suggestion, you can keep the door open for other transformations by using the [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

Add a method `dispatch_visit` to the Sprite hierarchy, using covariant return types:

```
class Sprite{
    virtual HTMLSprite * dispatch_visit( HTMLConvert_ const &c ) const = 0;
};
class Character : public Sprite {
    virtual HTMLCharacter * dispatch_visit( HTMLConvert_ const &c ) const
        { return c( this ); }
};
class Markup : public Sprite {
    virtual HTMLMarkup * dispatch_visit( HTMLConvert_ const &c ) const
        { return c( this ); }
};
```

This allows each object to notify the converter of its dynamic type — essentially, a dynamic dispatch into the parallel type, or even a parallel type hierarchy. Everything else pretty much works as your code is written… the best candidate is chosen among the `operator()()` functions of the converter, based on the static parameter type.

Oh, you'll need to add the "missing function" to the converter:

```
struct HTMLConvert_ {
  HTMLSprite * operator () (const Sprite * c) { return c->dispatch_visit( *this ); }
  HTMLCharacter * operator () (const Character * c) { return new HTMLCharacter (); }
  HTMLMarkup * operator () (const Markup * c) { return new HTMLMarkup (); }
} HTMLConvert;
```

Hmm, that repetitive function could be encapsulated by a template… this only seems to work in C++0x if you want the `visitable` template to automatically determine the return type of `dispatch_visit`. If you don't like `principal_base` you can factor it out.

```
#include <functional>

template< class T >
struct principal_base
    { typedef void type; };

template< class Client, class Visitor,
    class Base = typename principal_base< Client >::type >
struct visitable :
    virtual visitable< typename principal_base< Client >::type, Visitor > {
    virtual typename std::result_of< Visitor( Client * ) >::type
    dispatch_visit( Visitor const &v ) const
        { return v( static_cast< Client const * >( this ) ); }
};

template< class Client, class Visitor >
struct visitable< Client, Visitor, void > {
    virtual typename std::result_of< Visitor( Client * ) >::type
    dispatch_visit( Visitor const &v ) const = 0;
};

class HTMLSprite { /* ... */ };
class HTMLCharacter : public HTMLSprite {};
class HTMLMarkup : public HTMLSprite {};

class Sprite;
class Character;
class Markup;

struct HTMLConvert_ {
  HTMLSprite * operator () (const Sprite * c);
  HTMLCharacter * operator () (const Character * c);
  HTMLMarkup * operator () (const Markup * c);
} HTMLConvert;

class Sprite : public visitable< Sprite, HTMLConvert_ > {};
template<> struct principal_base< Character >
    { typedef Sprite type; };
class Character : public Sprite, visitable< Character, HTMLConvert_ > {};
template<> struct principal_base< Markup >
    { typedef Sprite type; };
class Markup : public Sprite, visitable< Markup, HTMLConvert_ > {};

//class Invalid : Character, Markup {};

HTMLSprite * HTMLConvert_::operator () (const Sprite * c)
    { return c->dispatch_visit( *this ); }
HTMLCharacter * HTMLConvert_::operator () (const Character * c)
    { return new HTMLCharacter (); }
HTMLMarkup * HTMLConvert_::operator () (const Markup * c)
    { return new HTMLMarkup (); }
```

Comment: This looks like what I might end up doing. It's unfortunate that I can't have a templated virtual `dispatch_visit` to try and avoid the redundancy. I'm quickly headed into the limits of my understanding of the C++ language here.

Comment: @ezpz: I don't see why templated `dispatch_visit` should be impossible; I tried to come up with one for this answer but got stuck needing a `decltype`/`typeof` operator. So it's easier in C++0x, in any case. (You can't have a templated virtual function, but you can have a virtual function in a templated base class.)

Comment: @ezpz: Updated with such a template. Does require C++0x as written, but you could work around that.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest adding the function to convert to HTML type to each class. So you'd have a virtual `Convert` function as a member of `Sprite` and each derived class can override it. Then when you call the `Convert` function on your list of `Sprite *`s, it will call the appropriate converter. You'll need to forward declare the return type (`HTMLSprite`).

There are probably more elegant ways, but this idea allows you to use virtual functions.

The problem with your suggestion is that the pointers in the array are all type `Sprite *` regardless of what they actually point to, so a `Sprite *` is what will be passed to your function. Instead, use something like mem_fun to make a struct that will call the member; this will call the appropriate function through a virtual call:

```
std::transform(sprites.begin (), sprites.end (), html.begin (), mem_fun(&Sprite::Convert));
```

Comment if you need me to clarify anything.

Comment: The problem I see with that is that now my `Sprite` class has to be aware of any potential conversion target. I was hoping to expose an interface and support changes to arbitrary representations without having the internal structure aware of the details of such conversions.

Comment: You may need to jump though some hoops for that. I understand that it isn't ideal, but to properly convert the class, you'll need private access. That means either a member or a friend (or a completely exposed class), either of which must be declared in the class definition. The fully exposed class is probably the cleanest option, but you'll still need a way to identify the type that a Sprite * is actually pointing to. This could be done with a `whatAmI` virtual function. But, like I said, it gets messy quick. Someone else on here probably has an elegant solution; I'd be interested in it.

Comment: @ezpz: Then you can have a parallel traits class for each kind of conversion, yet still use polymorphism by the visitor pattern. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern

Answer (score 1):

How about an abstract factory?

```
       +-----------------+                            +--------+         
       |  RenderFactory  |                            | Sprite |
       |=================|                            +--------+
       | CreateSprite()  |                                 /\
       | CreateMarkup()  |                         +------------------+
       +-----------------+                         |                  |
               /\                            +------------+    +-------------+
       +-----------------+              ....>| HTMLSprite |    | PlainSprite |
       |                 |              :    +------------+    +-------------+
+----------------+   +----------------+ :
| PlainFactory   |   |  HTMLFactory   | :
|================|   |================| :                 +--------+
| CreateSprite() |   | CreateSprite() |.:...              | Markup |
| CreateMarkup() |   | CreateMarkup() |..  :              +--------+
+----------------+   +----------------+    :                  /\
                                           :          +----------------+
                                           :          |                |
                                           :    +------------+   +-------------+
                                            ..> | HTMLMarkup |   | PlainMarkup |
                                                +------------+   +-------------+
```

Comment: Wow - ascii-licious drawing :) Although, this looks like it doubles the work I need to do at the parsing stage. The idea is that I will only parse once and allow for multiple output forms via this transformation.

Answer (score 0):

As your convert will need to know about all the types to convert from and too it is performing a mapping function.

Here is my quick hack

```
struct HTMLConvert_ {
  HTMLSprite * operator () (const Sprite* const& sp ) { 
    Character const * c = dynamic_cast<Character const *>(sp);
    if( c )
      return new HTMLCharacter (c);

    Markup const * m = dynamic_cast<Markup const *>(sp);
    if( c )
      return new HTMLMarkup (m);
  }
} HTMLConvert;
```

Comment: This quickly turns into a RTTI switch statement. In the case of many types this is not really preferable - I should have mentioned that I have many types :)